# $("#myKendoGrid").data("kendoGrid") is undefined after opening (and closing) jQuery UI dlg

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, kendo-grid

I'm facing a strange problem.
After opening (and closing) a jQuery UI modal dialog, the kendo UI grid .data i.e. `var grd = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid")` on the page from where the dialog is called becomes undefined. 
The kendo grid works perfectly fine till the dialog is opened (and closed).
The kendo grid however displays data as it was before opening (and closing) the dialog. The .data starts working after a page refresh.

Are there any known issues in doing this or am I missing something here?

jQuery version - 1.7.1
jQuery UI version - 1.8.11
kendo UI version - v2011.3.1129

jQuery UI dialog code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            "Dismiss": function () {
                debugger;
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog").html("");
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: $(this).attr("abc"),
        //close: function () { debugger; return false; },
        modal: true,
        height: 800,
        width: 1150,
        left: 0
    }).load(this.href);
});
```

kendo grid code:

```
$("#myGrid").html("");
$("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds
            , sortable: true
            , selectable: true
            , scrollable: true
            , height: 400
            , columns: [
            , {title: "Auto", template: '#=myFunc(xyz)#', width: myWidth }
```

.....

Answer (score -1):

We ended up solving this problem by switching to from jQuery UI dialog to Kendo Window.